# Where are the privacy policies for medical devices?

Tags: united-states, privacy, medical

Some medical devices transmit patient data, usually to the device manufacturer, who then shares the data with the doctor and possibly the insurer.  In my experiences, the patient is given little or no information about such surveillance.  Sometimes the information given is incorrect.

When I've proactively tried to find a privacy policy, I've always come up empty.  This seems strange since nearly every commercial website publicly posts a privacy policy, yet medical device manufacturers don't provide this information to patients.  (Of course, in our world, that patients are not the customers.  Manufacturers and models are often selected by doctors.)

I'm in the United States, which has privacy requirements for patient data (e.g., HIPAA), and California, which has additional consumer privacy requirements.  Are medical devices somehow exempted from regulations that require notice of data collection, how and with whom that data is shared, retention periods, etc.?

Comment: You may consider the possibility that the manufacturer simply relays data tied to the serial number of the device.  The doctor's office would then correlate the serial number to patient's identifying information.  If the manufacturer doesn't have any patient information there would be no HIPAA violation.  How this works would be a legitimate question for your doctor.

Comment: @MichaelHall:  If you change doctors, you must tell the device manufacturer which doctor should receive your data.  To do so, you have to prove you're the patient (you wouldn't want it possible for just anyone to redirect your data).  This demonstrates the manufacturer can identify specific patients' data.  Even if they do so in a limited capacity, it seems notice should be required.  Doctors responsible for three different devices in my immediate family have been unwilling or unable to answer basic questions about how this works.

Comment: Ah, disregard that theory then.  Thx.

Comment: The data collected, contained in, and transmitted by medical devices are constrained by both the HIPAA Privacy and Security rules. If a formal Privacy Policy for a given take-home medical device exists, you could get it by asking the manufacturer directly. You would likely have more luck asking about their data collection and retention policies, which are formal but not in the same way a Privacy Policy is.

Comment: @MichaelHall It would be highly unusual to have an interface that only used a single identifier as you're describing—at least I've never seen one in 15+ years of working with them. There may even be regulatory requirements re a minimum set of patient identifiers (no one has ever asked me to omit them so I've never had cause to research that). FYI: Per the second part of your comment, the health data that the device collects would be protected under HIPAA even if de identified.

Comment: @Michael:  Thanks for the pointer.  It seems reasonable that HIPAA privacy rule (among others) would apply. However, reading portions of the HIPAA privacy rule (45 CFR Parts 160 and 164) it's unclear whether the manufacturer of a take-home or implanted medical device that collect and transmit health data is a "covered entity" so those rules may not apply.  Specifically, the rule grants patients a notice right.  I've never seen one from a manufacturer.  To know to request a notice requires knowing that your implant(s) collect and transmit data in the first place.

Comment: Whether or not they are a covered entity (at least with respect to their device) would hinge on whether they receive and warehouse the date, or if the data is sent straight to the physician/office/hospital/etc overseeing the patient's care. How the device itself retrieves, stores, and transmits data is the purview of FDA

Comment: It seems at least one manufacturer believes their responsibility to notify under HIPAA is to the _customer_, who is often _not the patient_ but the "[hospital, physician, or other healthcare provider](medtronic.com/us-en/about/corporate-governance/us-patient-privacy-principles.html)."